# how to make conditional content projection in Angular?

Tags: angular, web-component

I want to make an optional content projection in Angular.
The whole thing should look like this, for example:

```
<app-root>  
   <app-header></app-header>  
</app-root>
```

A default header is to be output here.

```
<app-root>  
   <app-header>  
      <div>Custom Header Text</div>  
  </app-header>  
</app-root>
```

Default header must not be displayed. Only the inner part of the app header in the background of the header.component. I need the whole thing for a web component.

I want to display an ng-content, only if an inner part of the element is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, you can achieve optional content projection using the ng-content directive along with ng-template. Here's how you can implement it:

In your app-header.component.html, define the structure of your header component. Use the ng-content directive to project content into your header if provided:

```
<div class="header-container">
  <!-- Default content -->
  <ng-content select="default-content"></ng-content>
  
  <!-- Custom content -->
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

In your app-root.component.html, use the app-header component and provide the default content using the ng-template element with the #defaultContent reference:

```
<app-header>
  <ng-template #defaultContent>
    <div>Default Header Text</div>
  </ng-template>
  
  <!-- Custom content -->
  <div>Custom Header Text</div>
</app-header>
```

In your app-header.component.ts, you can use ContentChild to check if the default content is provided or not:

```
import { Component, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './app-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-header.component.css']
})
export class AppHeaderComponent {
  @ContentChild('defaultContent') defaultContentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  hasDefaultContent(): boolean {
    return !!this.defaultContentTemplate;
  }
}
```

Finally, in your app-header.component.html, you can conditionally display the default content based on whether it's provided or not:

```
<div class="header-container">
  <!-- Default content -->
  <ng-container *ngIf="hasDefaultContent(); else customContent">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="defaultContentTemplate"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  
  <!-- Custom content -->
  <ng-template #customContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

This way, when you use the  component, the default content will be displayed only if the ng-template with the reference #defaultContent is provided inside it. If you don't provide the ng-template, the custom content will be displayed as the header.